# Creating different Drawable instances from the same icon

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to use a circle icon to display a few circles inside my activity, each one set to a different color.
To do that I tried this code:

```
Drawable solidCircle = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.solid_circle);
solid.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

(The color is randomly selected)

My problem is that all the circles get the same color - the last one I called `setColorFilter` for, I assume because the drawable is always the same instance.

My question is how do I use different Drawable instances of the same circle so I can do that without having to duplicate my assets?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this you can simply clone the drawable.

```
Drawable clone = drawable.getConstantState().newDrawable();
```